# AngularJs - push Object in array

Tags: angularjs

I can't understand how to push object into an array I tried few different ways and still can't figured it out.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp',[])
app.controller('dropdown', function($scope, $http){
 $scope.userInfo = [];
 
 $scope.pushInArray = function() {
  $scope.userInfo.push($scope.users)
 }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="dropdown">

<input type="text" name="name" ng-model="users.name" placeholder="Name">
<input type="text" name="email" ng-model="users.email" placeholder="Email">
<input type="text" name="phoneNo" ng-model="users.phoneNo" placeholder="phone Number">
<button ng-click="pushInArray()">Add</button>
<pre>{{userInfo}}</pre>
</div>
```

at click of add button I push the users information in userInfo properities. I works on first time but If I modified the the value already stored value also modified(after push value is modifying).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `angular.copy`, this will copy the exist object with a new instance.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp',[])
app.controller('dropdown', function($scope, $http){
 $scope.userInfo = [];
 
 $scope.pushInArray = function() {
    var user = angular.copy($scope.users);
  $scope.userInfo.push(user);
 }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="dropdown">

<input type="text" name="name" ng-model="users.name" placeholder="Name">
<input type="text" name="email" ng-model="users.email" placeholder="Email">
<input type="text" name="phoneNo" ng-model="users.phoneNo" placeholder="phone Number">
<button ng-click="pushInArray()">Add</button>
<pre>{{userInfo}}</pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to empty yours `users` before setting it to new values:

```
$scope.userInfo = [];

$scope.pushInArray = function(data) {
    $scope.userInfo.push(data)
    $scope.users = null;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" name="name" ng-model="users.name" placeholder="Name">
<input type="text" name="email" ng-model="users.email" placeholder="Email">
<input type="text" name="phoneNo" ng-model="users.phoneNo" placeholder="phone Number">
<button ng-click="pushInArray(users)">Add</button>
<pre>{{userInfo}}</pre>
```

Here is the working [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/4LZ6EAgQDoShuIosWKEm?p=preview)

Comment: Its working fine, Is there any way to do without making users properities as null

Comment: Why you don't want to set it to null?

Comment: just I want to know is there any way

Comment: @AayushiJain yea I forgot to null it haha nice answer bud :)

Comment: @vinox: I don't think you can make it without setting it to null as the name/email/phoneNo values will persist in `users` unless you reinitialize them

Comment: @Mike: Thanks! :)

Comment: wish we could just share the best answer @AayushiJain since we have the same soln lol

Comment: @Mike: Hahaha, true!

Comment: If I make null means user entered value in input field is removed. I want to stay that old value in the field

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the object to the scope function to persist it.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[])
app.controller('dropdown', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.userInfo = [];

    $scope.pushInArray = function(data) {
        var entry = (JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)));
        $scope.userInfo.push(entry);
    }

});

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="dropdown">

<input type="text" name="name" ng-model="users.name" placeholder="Name">
<input type="text" name="email" ng-model="users.email" placeholder="Email">
<input type="text" name="phoneNo" ng-model="users.phoneNo" placeholder="phone Number">
<button ng-click="pushInArray(users)">Add</button>
<pre>{{userInfo}}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: same thing happening after first value push If I modified input text value pushed object value also modified

Comment: yea I forgot to add the `$scope.users = null` to clear it as per @Aayushi's answer

Comment: can I know the reason why stringify the data and again parse the data

Comment: instead of doing, you can use default angular function angular.copy to achieve. refer @Pengyy answer

Comment: It's just if you wanted to do vanilla JavaScript